# How to establish if a car has CAN Bus?

Tags: can-bus

Can someone please help me on ways to establish if a car has a CAN Bus? I am specifically looking for?

1. Physical or Technical/Electrical examination to check if its a CAN Bus
2. I have read about `ISO 15765-4.3:2001` standards, but I am looking for a global approach and more discrete way to establish (for cars manufactured/assembled in various geographies)

Answer (score 1):

Most European vehicles will have at least one CAN bus if it was manufactured after 2004.

So find out specifically it requires experience and research of each manufacturer. For example I know off the top of my head that PSA vehicles all have CAN bus after late 2003.

To find out physically often the easiest way is to look at the wires to the OBD port, if you have a twisted pair going to pins 6&14 it has CAN bus

Comment: It is ports 6 and 14 or 7 and 14?

Comment: Yes sorry I've updated